# How can i force apt-get or apt to use only https connections

Tags: debian, networking, apt, package-management, https

I am running a mongo db docker container on a network using only https. The container uses apt-get for installing packages. Since network allows only https connections,apt-get is not working for me. 
I have tried to change http with https in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d after installing apt-transport-https. But  nothing worked for me. 
Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list after replacing https with https

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb https://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
```

The mongodb-org.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d looks like

```
deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 main
```

after doing all this apt-get update shows

```
Get:1 https://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease [384 B]
Ign https://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Get:2 https://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 Release.gpg [801 B]
Hit https://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 Release
Get:3 https://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease [309 B]
Ign https://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit https://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Ign https://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign https://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 Release
Get:4 https://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.2/main amd64 Packages [10.6 kB]
Hit https://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign https://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Ign https://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Get:5 https://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [337 B]
Err https://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Hit https://deb.debian.org jessie Release
Err https://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err https://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Get:6 https://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [329 B]
Err https://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err https://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Fetched 9110 kB in 8s (1096 kB/s)
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1570654450
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 20 337
W: Failed to fetch https://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: This is an interesting find.  It appears that [`security.debian.org`](https://security.debian.org/) presents an SSL certificate for `schmelzer.debian.org`.  This is failing for good reason!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The security updates can't be retrieved from https connection , explained on [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)

> The `security.debian.org` hosts currently do not have publicly verifiable SSL certificates on HTTPS and hence cannot be used with HTTPS at the moment.

Your can edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follow:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
```

To solve the gpg key error for MongoDB , you should update the gpg key, see I[mport the public key used by the package management system](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system):

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: can i remove security.debian.org and use HTTPS version for others ? any issue because of that ?

Comment: @xaglez The issue is you can't receive the security updates. It is strongly recommended to keep the security repository in your sources.

Comment: The issue is my network only allows HTTPS connections  and blocks all incoming and outgoing HTTP connections .So if we keep security repository ,which only have HTTP mirror i will not be able to do apt operations

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian, update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` entries to point to the official https mirror redirector:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ <dist> <suite>
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ <dist> <suite>
```

e.g. for Debian unstable:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
```

You can refer these for more-

[Uasigned bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1464064)

Comment: `deb https://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main
 deb https://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
 deb https://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main `
i have changed my source.list like this .But im not able to use apt-get or apt for installing packages